# Query redshift grouping by similar strings

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Amazon redshift that lists api endpoints and their usage, and need to query the usage stats. Unfortunately some of the endpoints include ids in the name, so I need a way of grouping by the endopint regardless of what id is in the url.

Example data:

```
endpoint
'a/b/c'
'a/b/c/19'
'd/20'
'd/1'
'e/f'
'e/f'
```

I need a query that would take this data and output

```
endpoint, count(*)
'a/b/c/*', 2
'd/*',     2
'e/f'      2
```

So far I have just tried to exclude ones with specific ids using something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
    endpoint, count(*) 
FROM 
    api_requests 
WHERE 
    endpoint NOT LIKE '%/[0-9]/%'
GROUP BY 
    endpoint 
ORDER BY 
    count(*) 
DESC;
```

But
a) This doesn't work for some reason, and
b) ideally I would group them by the id instead

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Given `a/b/c`, `a/b/d`, and `a/e/f`, should the output be `a/*` with a count of a 3, or `a/b/` with a count of two and `a/e/f` with a count of 1?

Comment: That depends on whether c, d, e and f are integer ids or strings. If they are ids, like `a/b/1`, `a/b/2`, `a/10/f`, that would be `a/b` with a count of 2 and `a/*` with a count of 1. There will only ever be one integer id in the string though so we won't get something like `a/1/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(endpoint, '/[0-9]+$', '') as canonical,
       count(*)
from api_requests 
group by canonical;
```

This gets rid of the last group group if it is all numbers.

Comment: This works amazingly for the ones with ids at the end thank you very much, but still does not sort the ones with ids in the middle, e.g `a/b/123/c` and `a/b/321/c`. Can i do a double regex type thing? I have tried using


`select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(endpoint, '/[0-9]+$', '/id'), '/[0-9]/+$', '/id/') as canonical,
       count(*)
from api_requests 
group by canonical order by count(*) desc;`


But this does not seem to work

Comment: @KathyRindhoops . . . Your question has no examples of such.  You should be able to modify the `regexp_replace()` for that purpose (by looking for a pattern ending in a slash).  If you can't figure that out, I would recommend asking a *new* question with more appropriate data.

Comment: Ah you're right, I forgot to add that example. Will add a new question now cheers